# UITextView -rac_textsignal does not work when text is changed by iOS correction

Tags: ios, uitextview, reactive-cocoa

It seems like UITextView -rac_textsignal does not work when text is changed programmatically, e.g. by iOS correction. The binding is like this.

```
RAC(self, viewModel.text) = self.textView.rac_textSignal;
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 6):

The `-rac_textSignal` method derives from the `UITextView`'s `-textViewDidChange:` delegate method, which is called on text changes only from the UI, not programmatically. To fix this, we need to merge another signal. Like this...

```
RAC(self, viewModel.text) = 
[RACSignal merge:@[self.textView.rac_textSignal, RACObserve(self, textView.text)]]
```

Comment: Just a small hint: you probably have a retain cycle here. A simple solution to get rid of it is to simply use: `RAC(self, viewModel.text) = [RACSignal merge:@[self.textView.rac_textSignal, RACObserve(self, textView.text)]]`.

Comment: Thanks! Edited my answer. Memory management in RAC is always tricky T_T.

Comment: Finally someone explains me that :) Hours lost.. Thanks